# How to impose a lower bound to the smallest singular value?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, singularity

Is there a simple transformation to apply to a matrix $A$ so that its smallest singular value becomes larger than an arbitrary value $\epsilon$, while the other singular values are perturbed as little as possible?

Comment: We can compute precisely what that transformation is if we know the SVD of $A$. Question is, how much do we know about $A$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom We know the exact numerical value of $A$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I don't know whether the above was not clear enough, but I meant that we know everything about $A$.

Comment: so can I assume that we know the SVD of $A$, or is computing the SVD prohibitively expensive?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, we know the SVD of $A$

Answer (score 0):

For example: $A+(\sigma_{n-1}-\sigma_n)u_nv_n^T$ will have the same SVD as $A$ except with $\sigma_{n}=\sigma_{n-1}$.